# Query sub collection - majority mutual ids that contains in list

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, intersection

Consider the following list:

```
List<long> listOfIDs = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

> [(Product) 1 Pineapple - (Supplier) Fruit Inc / Marketplace Inc]>
>
> [2 Strawberry - Fruit Inc]>
>
> [3 Coke - Super Drinks Inc / Marketplace Inc]>
>
> [4 Orange Juice - Super Drinks Inc]

```
db.Table.Where(a => a.SubTable.All(b => listOfIds.Contains(b.SubTableId)))
```

While I've selected Products 1 and 2, I should get only Fruit Inc as a Supplier. When I include Coke into my list, I **don't want to see any supplier anymore** because there is no Supplier that represents these 3 products at the same time.

Expected Outputs Scenarios:

Selected Products: 1, 2
Expected Result: Fruit Inc

1, 3
Marketplace Inc

1, 2, 3
**Empty.**

1, 3, 4
**Empty.**

3, 4
Super Drinks Inc

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: @IvanStoev What I'm doing wrong that I'm not getting the EXPECTED results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally got what's the issue.

So you have a two entities with `many-to-many` relationship like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and given a list with product Ids, you want to get the list of suppliers that provide all the products from the list.

There are at least two ways you could do that:

```
List<long> productIds = ...;
```

(A) Similar to your attempt, but switching the roles of `All` and`Contains`:

```
var suppliers = db.Suppliers
    .Where(s => productIds.All(id => s.Products.Any(p => p.Id == id)))
    .ToList();
```

or if you prefer `Contains` (both generate one and the same SQL):

```
var suppliers = db.Suppliers
    .Where(s => productIds.All(id => s.Products.Select(p => p.Id).Contains(id)))
    .ToList();
```

(B) Counting the matches:

```
var suppliers = db.Suppliers
    .Where(s => s.Products.Count(p => productIds.Contains(p.Id)) == productIds.Count)
    .ToList();
```

I can't say which one is better performance wise, but all they produce the desired result and are supported by LINQ to Entities.

Comment: you got my exactly needing. In fact, I do have two entities with many-to-many. Thank you for your clear answer and capacity of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems depends on the fact that a given supplier can have more products related to it then those contained in your filter list.

You should resolve this issue simply exchanging the container of data source against which to test your condition in your linq query:

```
db.Table.Where(a => listOfIds.All(b => a.SubTable.Contains(b)))
```

You can also read this query in this way:

> get all the suppliers (`a` records) for which is true that **all**
>   products (`b` elements) contained in `listOfIds` **must be also
>   contained** in products list related to each supplier (`a.SubTable`).